# How to escape only the double quotes inside middle of text in UNIX?

Tags: string, unix

How we can escape the double quotes inside of string in UNIX,

```
ex: inputString :"BordtelefonJon"Sentralbord"" 
OutputString: "BordtelefonJon/"Sentralbord/""
```

can anyone help me on this??

Comment: Take a look at the "sed" utility, you will find lots of examples on the internet.

Comment: what you've tried so far?

Comment: Are you talking about a full line in a file or is this a substring?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape any character wit `\`. For example your input should be like:

```
"BordtelefonJon\"Sentralbord\""
```

and this will output:

```
BordtelefonJon"Sentralbord"
```

to get the output you posted in your question your input should be:

```
"BordtelefonJon/\"Sentralbord/\""
```